# How can I change IronPython interpreter welcome message?

Tags: python, c#, configuration

This is the interpreter welcome message

[image: 1]

I want to change that message to a custom one, but  I dont't know where the configuration file is.

Comment: mmm... but why?

Comment: I'm working on a project where I have to use iron python interpreter as it relates between python and .NET , I want to change some things in ironpyhton such as the welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already downloaded the source code for IronPython. This will give you access to the internals of the interpreter, allowing you to modify its behavior.

In the source, you'll want to find where the welcome message is printed. This might be in a file related to the console or REPL. You can use a search tool or command (like `grep` on Unix systems or Find in Files feature in many text editors) to look for a distinctive part of the current welcome message.

Once you've located the line of code that prints the welcome message, you can change it to whatever custom message you'd like.

After modifying the source, you'll need to recompile IronPython to produce a new executable that includes your changes. The compilation process might vary based on the version of IronPython and the development environment you're using.
Once recompiled, you can run your custom version of the IronPython interpreter, and it should display your custom welcome message.